# for HTTPS application

Tags: apache-flex, flex3

I need to develop the HTTPS application using Flex and Java.

But i have idea about remote objects or HTTPServices. 
Any one please help me which one is the best for developing  HTTPS application.

Thanks,
Ravi

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My feeling is that if you only need to connect with a flex client then go with the remote objects. If you want the flexibility to connect with other clients then go ahead and use HTTPS

Comment: @Steve: Thanks for your response. Can you please explain briefly?

Comment: I mean that if you want to connect with iPhone and flex then use HTTPS, if it is only flex then use remote objects since it will be more efficient